# ASP.NET MVC 3 - An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

When I do:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Translations[ViewBag.Languages[i].CultureCode].Title)
<br/>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Translations[ViewBag.Languages[i].CultureCode].PreviewDescription)
<br/>
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Translations[ViewBag.Languages[i].CultureCode].FullDescription)
```

I am doing simpler TextBoxFor's earlier, e.g:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ContactName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress)
```

At the top of the View, my using statement is similar to: `@model x.y.z.Listing`

Answer (score 4):

As the message says, you are using viewbag, which is a dynamic operation, in your lambda expression:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Translations[ViewBag.Languages[i].CultureCode].Title)
```

To solve you issue, simply move the dynamics out, like this

```
@{
    string cultureCode = ViewBag.Languages[i].CultureCode
}

 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Translations[cultureCode].Title)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have to check that you are using stongly-typed view.

Comment: This might work better as a comment, but it's a good point nonetheless.